# Reduce "chrome" in Google Translate?

Tags: google-translate

Is there a way to get rid of the top toolbar "chrome" of Google Translate? It takes up too much screen real estate on a laptop screen. I would rather see the translated page only and nothing else.

[image: Google Translate screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible get rid of the Google Translate chrome completely so that all you see is the translated page fullscreen and nothing else.

Install Google Chrome (or chromium-browser if you prefer). Open Google Chrome and click on the Settings icon that is in the top right-hand corner. A popup menu will appear. From this menu select **Settings**. The Settings window will open. In the search box in the Settings window type "translate" without the quotation marks. The Settings window will change to show the search results for "translate". In the search results for "translate" you will see a checkbox that says: "Offer to translate pages that aren't in a language I read". Click this checkbox in order to put a check mark in it.

Now browse to a webpage that you want to be translated. A toolbar will appear asking you if you want the webpage to be translated. After you are finished using the translate toolbar, you can close it by clicking on the X in the right-hand side of the toolbar.